# Why does my prefix operation program not work when I enter more than 2 integers in a row?

Tags: java, stack, prefix-operator

My program works properly when I only enter 1 or 2 integers in a row such as: + 13 24 or * 4 - 165 235. But if I enter % * 5 12 8 it does not give me the right answer. How can I change my loops so that it works when there is a longer string of integers in a row. Given the order of operations and format of prefix notation? *My stack class and its methods do work properly.

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class part1Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // Reference variables
    String temp2;
    int num, num1, num2, ch;
    char op;
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    PrefixStack<Character> operands = new PrefixStack<Character>();
    PrefixStack<Integer> S = new PrefixStack<Integer>();

    System.out.print("Do you want to perform a prefix operation?");
    System.out.print(" 1 for yes or 0 to quit: ");
    ch = keyboard.nextInt();
    temp2 = keyboard.nextLine();

    while(ch != 0){
        System.out.print('\n'+ "Enter the operation with a space between "
                + "each character. End your operation with a period: ");

        while(keyboard.hasNext()){
            if (keyboard.hasNextInt()){
                num = keyboard.nextInt();
                S.push(num);}
            else{
                temp2 = keyboard.next();
                switch(temp2.charAt(0)){
                    case '+': operands.push('+');
                        break;
                    case '-': operands.push('-');
                        break;
                    case '/': operands.push('/');
                        break;
                    case '*': operands.push('*');
                        break;
                    case '%': operands.push('%');
                        break;
                }
            }
            if(temp2.charAt(0) == '.')
                break;
        }

        while(S.size > 1){
            op = operands.pop();
            num2 = S.pop();
            num1 = S.pop();
            switch(op){
                case '+': S.push(num1 + num2);;
                    break;
                case '-': S.push(num1 - num2);;
                    break;
                case '/': S.push(num1 / num2);;
                    break;
                case '*': S.push(num1 * num2);;
                    break;
                case '%': S.push(num1 % num2);
                    break;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Your operation = " + S.pop());

        System.out.print('\n'+"Do you want to perform another operation?");
        System.out.print(" 1 for yes or 0 to quit: ");
        ch = keyboard.nextInt();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: what answer did you get, and what answer did you expect?  Have you tried printing out the intermediate values?

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you are using is wrong!

For example, suppose you give:

```
% * 5 12 8
```

your program will output `5` as answer

It will push % and * on stack and 5 12 and 8 on stack

Then it will take out 8 and 12 and take out * and do `8 * 12 = 96` and push it on stack

Now in next round it will take out 96 and 5 and % as operator and do `5 % 96 = 5` which is given as output

Here you need to consider 2 very important thing:

1. % operator has same precedence as * and / (in Java). But the prefix expression is not evaluated in a way your program is doing it:

   `% * 5 12 8` should be evaluated as:

   `(5 * 12) % 8` which is `4`.

   So update your algorithm.
2. Your algorithm does not consider operator precedence. Add that feature in your program!

   Try out some examples [here](http://prefix-calc.appspot.com/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

"Order of operations is defined within the structure of prefix notation and can be easily determined. One thing to keep in mind is that when executing an operation, the operation is applied to the first operand by the second operand. This is not an issue with operations that commute, but for non-commutative operations like division or subtraction, this fact is crucial to the analysis of a statement. For example, the following statement:

```
/ 10 5
```

is read as "divide 10 by 5". Thus the solution is 2, not 1/2 as would be the result of an incorrect analysis.

Since you didn't post what the wrong results are, I'm assuming this is your problem